# Commerce show customer only once even with multiple orders

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to print a list of customers but display a customer only once even when he/she ordered multiple times?

```
    {% set orders = craft.orders.completed(true).limit(null).orderBy('dateOrdered desc').all() %}
    {% for order in orders %}
       <li>
         {{ order.billingAddress.firstName}}
         {{ order.billingAddress.lastName}}
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

This works but it prints the names for each order. I want to print the customer only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`group` Twig filter in Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#group). You can group the orders by customer and then output them with two for-loops.

Here's some example code using only the customer ID and order ID:

```
{% set orders = craft.orders.completed(true).limit(null).orderBy('dateOrdered desc').all() %}
{% set ordersByCustomerId = orders | group(order => order.customerId) %}

{% for customer, customerOrders in ordersByCustomerId %}
    <h2>{{ customer }}</h2>

    {% for order in customerOrders %}
        {{ order.id }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```